# PHP: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php, spintax

I'm trying this new script on my server and I can't seem to figure out why it keeps giving me the error of:

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /includes/classes/spin_article.php on line 51

**This line is giving the error -->** $string = file_get_contents($files[rand(1, count($files)) -1]);

```
<?PHP
class Spintax
{
    public function process($text)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback(
            '/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x',
            array($this, 'replace'),
            $text
        );
    }

    public function replace($text)
    {
        $text = $this->process($text[1]);
        $parts = explode('|', $text);
        return $parts[array_rand($parts)];
    }
}
?>

<?PHP
ob_start();
$files = glob("spintax_articles/*.txt");
$spintax = new Spintax();
$string = file_get_contents($files[rand(1, count($files)) -1]);
echo $spintax->process($string);
$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
$fp = fopen("content.txt","w");
fwrite($fp,$page);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Go ahead and `print_r($files)`, You'll find a value in glob that isn't a file.

Comment: `$files[rand(1, count($files)) -1]` obviously has no value. You need to make sure `4files` contains values you expect before trying to use them.

Comment: My guess is that there are no files matching the `glob`.

Comment: Also, Should it not be `$files[mt_rand(1, count($files)-1)]`?

Answer (score 2):

If there are actually matching files, then you may get a random index that is 1 greater than the maximum.  Use:

```
$string = file_get_contents($files[rand(1, count($files)-1)]);
```

Notice the `-1` placement.

And just in case there is no files you should check for that, using a condition.

```
<?php
$files = glob("spintax_articles/*.txt");

if(!empty($files)) {

    $spintax = new Spintax();
    $string  = file_get_contents($files[mt_rand(1, count($files)-1)]);

    $fp = fopen("content.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fp, $spintax->process($string));
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: About the `-1` placement, doesn't that give you the same upper value but a lower value of `1`, meaning you'll never select the first item of the array? The OP's version looks fine to me.

Comment: Or theres simply `file_get_contents($files[array_rand($files)]);`, but ive vandalized you answer too much already ;p